# Placing components in Android studio using arrays?

Tags: android, arrays, grid

I'm trying to place and manage 7x7 grid using imageswitchers in android studio, however, i am not sure how i am supposed to do this. I have been using android studio for a few days and i have been programming for a few months, do anyone have any tips on how to do this? What is the smartest way?

Comment: Would this help? http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-imageswitcher.html

Comment: I believe that helped a lot, thanks for the quick answer:)